# Load more button with useFetch (concatenate old and new array)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I have a computed URL property.

```
const params = ref<any>({
   pagination: {
       page: page.value,
       pageSize: pageSize.value,
   },
   populate: "*",
});

const url = computed(() => {
   return `http://localhost:1337/api/products?${qs.stringify(params.value)}`;
});
```

I use this URL to send a get request in Nuxt using useFetch

```
const { data: productsFetched } = await useFetch<any>(url);
const products = computed(() => flattenObj(productsFetched.value));
```

There is a function show more that needs to change the pageSize attr. of `params` which triggers the useFetch to send another request. The problem with this is that it will overwrite the data that I already have stored in the computed `products` property.
I tried to add some logic to my showMore function but i ended up wanting to change the computed property with array concatenation and of course it didn't let me do that. I tried to see if I could add login in the useFetch function, there is an option `onResponse` which accepts a function, but I can't access old data from useFetch.

How do i work around this problem?
Here is a snippet of my showMore function as of now.

```
const showMore = async () => {
    params.value = {
        ...params.value,
        pagination: {
            page: page.value + 1,
            pageSize: pageSize.value,
        },
    };

    const { data: newProducts } = await useFetch<any>(url);

    productsFetched.value = [...productsFetched.value, ...newProducts.value];
};
```

Of course this doesn't work since productsFetched cannot really accept a value i believe, it throws an error, and I can't assign the value to products since that one is computed. I really don't want to make a third variable because already i believe im doing something wrong.

Comment: You can refetch with new params. If you need to combine one paginated result with another then yes, you need a third variable

Comment: @EstusFlask Could you please provide a working example for what you mentioned ?

Comment: @RamyAhmed Something like `const { data, refresh } = await useFetch(url, { query: params }); ... params.value = ...; refresh()`. If it's not applicable to your case then consider asking a new question that reflects it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for this, the following worked for me:

```
const page = ref(1);
const productsFetched: any = ref([]);

const { data: products  }: any = await useFetch('url', {
params: { page },
watch: [page],
transform: (res: any) => {
    productsFetched.value = [...productsFetched.value, ...res.newProducts];
    return productsFetched.value;
  },
});

const loadMore = () => {
  page.value =++;
}
```